# Change button functionality jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've got this code in twig

```
 {% if followsId == null %}
            <div id="followUser" class="follow" data-userId="{{ profileUserData.id }}" data-currentUserId="{{ loggedUserData.id }}" data-action="follow">
                Follow
            </div>
 {% else %}
            <div id="unFollowUser" class="follow" data-followsId="{{ followsId }}">
                Unfollow
            </div>
 {% endif %}
```

I just wanted to change content and functionality to button on click and tried this code with jQuery

```
$('#followUser').click(function () {
    var userId       = $(this).attr('data-userId'),
        action       = $(this).attr('data-action'),
        currentUser  = $(this).attr('data-currentUserId');

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "/sci-profile/profile/follow",
        data: {
            userId: currentUser,
            profileUserId: userId,
            action: action
        },
        success: function(response)
        {
            $('#followUser').attr('id', 'unFollowUser')
                            .text('Unfollow')
                            .fadeOut(50)
                            .delay(50)
                            .fadeIn(50);
        }
    });
});
```

With this code on page source I see different ID and different text on button but when click second time I call first button like it had never changed. Is there some way to refresh memory for that element or I do wrong thing from start?

Comment: I had found solution with this question: **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686742/reload-js-function-when-load-element-with-ajax**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code should like this

```
{% if followsId == null %}
            <div data-action="follow" class="follow" data-user-id="{{ profileUserData.id }}">
                Follow
            </div>
 {% else %}
            <div data-action="unfollow" class="follow" data-user-id="{{ followsId }}">
                Unfollow
            </div>
 {% endif %}
```

No need to store current logged in user id, because you can grab it from session :)

Your Ajax Code should be like this

```
$('.follow').click(function () {
    var _this= $(this);
    var userId = $(this).data('user-id');
    var action =$(this).data('action');

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "/sci-profile/profile/follow",
        data: {
            profileUserId: userId,
            action: action
        },
        success: function(response)
        {
            if(action=="follow")
            {
                 _this.attr('data-action', 'unfollow').text('Unfollow');
            }
            else
            {
                 _this.attr('data-action', 'follow').text('Follow');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Hope you like my answer and up vote it, mark as correct if it is correct :)

Comment: +1, and you might want to use `$(document).on("click",".follow",function(event){ var $this = event.target; ..` for dynamically appended (ajax maybe) buttons.

Comment: That's not my question :) I'm just thinking forward as if that would be the asker's next problem :)

Comment: Rewind it back, this won't work :) you forgot to change the `$(this)` to `_this` after the second line.