# Reload JS function when load element with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

```
    $('#followUser').click(function () {
        var userId       = $(this).attr('data-userId'),
            action       = $(this).attr('data-action'),
            currentUser  = $(this).attr('data-currentUserId'),
            elem         = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/sci-profile/profile/follow",
            data: {
                userId: currentUser,
                profileUserId: userId,
                action: action
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                 elem.parent().load(window.location.href + ' #unFollowUser');
            }
        });
    });
```

After clicking on button, JS load new div with all its content, which is good, but problem starts at the moment when new div is loaded.

JS don't recognize new `ID`. And when I click on new button nothing happens because JS function has loaded when new element doesn't existed.

Is there a way to make some listener to check loads of new `DIV` and then load also JS function corresponding to that element `ID`?

Comment: [Event delegation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8594408/reload-javascript-file-after-an-ajax-request Maybe this link can help.

Comment: I spent some time to understand how to use .delegate() Thank you @Jo_bast for tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES, I made it.

This is html

```
 <div class="follow">
        {% if followsId == null %}
            <div id="followUser"  data-userId="{{ profileUserData.id }}" data-currentUserId="{{ loggedUserData.id }}" data-action="follow">
                Follow
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div id="unFollowUser" data-followsId="{{ followsId }}" data-action="unFollow">
                Unfollow
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        </div>
```

And there is JS code

```
$('.follow').delegate('div', 'click', function(){
    action       = $(this).attr('data-action');
    elem         = $(this);

    if (action == 'follow'){
        var userId       = $(this).attr('data-userId'),
            currentUser  = $(this).attr('data-currentUserId');

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "/sci-profile/profile/follow",
            data: {
                userId: currentUser,
                profileUserId: userId,
                action: action
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                elem.parent().load(window.location.href + ' #unFollowUser');
            }
        });
    }

    if (action == 'unFollow'){
        var followsId = $(this).attr('data-followsId');

        $.ajax({
            method: 'DELETE',
            url: "/sci-profile/profile/unFollow",
            data: {
                followsId: followsId
            },
            success: function(response)
            {
                elem.parent().load(window.location.href + ' #followUser');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I hope this will help to someone.

Comment: .delegate is deprecated. Use .on instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should use delegate

For example you have this markup

```
<div id=contentWrapper>
    .....some content here....
    <button type=button id=followUser></button>
</div>
```

- **#contentWrapper** - static block
- **anything inside it** - dynamic content

Now you should bind your event like that

```
$('#contentWrapper').on('click', '#followUser' 'function () {
    ...code here...
});
```